# Build failure while downloading Archiva Jars with maven

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-3, archiva

I would like to download [Archiva Rest API jars](http://archiva.apache.org/docs/1.4-M2/adminguide/webservices/rest.html) with maven 3 so I can make some Rest API and I always have a build failure. Here is  my POM :

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.archiva</groupId>
  <artifactId>archiva</artifactId>
  <version>1.4-M3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.archiva</groupId>
  <artifactId>archiva-rest-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.4-M3</version>
</dependency>
```

I always have this error :

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Remote Deployment 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/kohsuke/access-modifier-checker/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/kohsuke/access-modifier-checker/maven-metadata.xml (335 B at 1.6 KB/
sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/kohsuke/stapler/stapler/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/kohsuke/stapler/stapler/maven-metadata.xml (333 B at 5.1 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/archiva/archiva/1.4-M3/archiva-1.4-M3.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.820s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Nov 07 15:38:03 CET 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 25M/310M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project remote-deployment-new: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.ebiznext
.plugins:remote-deployment-new:hpi:1.0: Could not find artifact org.apache.archiva:archiva:jar:1.4-M3 in central (http:/
/repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
....
```

How can I resolve that ?

[EDIT] In fact, I am working on a Jenkins plugin where I want this plugin to download some jars in Archiva. For that, I will do some Rest services. This is why I need these dependencies. To make Rest call, on a archiva instances, we must add the archiva-rest-api dependency and a lot more. The thing is it does not download them (archiva-rest-api, jackson, apache cxf). Here is my POM :

```
  <dependencies>
   <dependency>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
  <version>1.9.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-xc</artifactId>
  <version>1.9.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
  <version>1.9.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
  <artifactId>cxf-bundle-jaxrs</artifactId>
  <version>2.6.3</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
      <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
<!-- <dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.archiva</groupId>
  <artifactId>archiva-rest-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.4-M4</version>
</dependency> -->
   </dependencies>
    <!-- get every artifact through repo.jenkins-ci.org, which proxies all the artifacts that we need -->


<repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>repo.jenkins-ci.org</id>
      <url>http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>repo.jenkins-ci.org</id>
      <url>http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is including the first dependency - `org.apache.archiva:archiva` contains no JAR artifact and Maven is complaining when it can't find it (see the [directory listing](http://search.maven.org/#browse|1597924731) in Maven central).

Try removing this dependency and trying again.

Comment: Hi Duncan, thanks for your reply. I have done what you say but this time I have a strange error.  I remove the first dependency, and when I run mvn package, the tests fail. This command works unless I remove all the dependencies of the project. The second thing I want to tell you is that I already search for this jar in the central repository. It seems to be there but I cant understand why maven cannot find it?

Comment: Ok. I have made some investigations. It seems that there is a problem with those 2 dependencies. I dont why. How can resolve this?

Comment: You need to be more specific about the errors you are seeing. Please edit your question to include more details about why your tests fail when you remove the first dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe have a look here some dependencies are detailed http://archiva.apache.org/docs/1.4-M3/adminguide/webservices/rest.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I already update my POM with those dependencies but it seems that they are downloaded in my local repo.